# apt - Pacote Apache2 não tem arquivo "apache2.conf"

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, lamp

Comecei recentemente a usar o Ubuntu 16.04 
Estou seguindo [este tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04) para instalar o LAMP.

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Depois de me deparar com vários erros, eu percebi que o pacote está vindo **sem o arquivo de configuração do apache**,`apache2.conf`.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Abaixo, coloquei a saída do comando `sudo apache2ctl configtest`

```
user@host:/$ sudo apache2ctl configtest
[sudo] password for user: 
/usr/sbin/apache2ctl: 165: /usr/sbin/apache2ctl: /usr/sbin/apache2: not found
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Comment: Para consulta futura, eu só consegui resolver esse problema formatando o sistema e reinstalando o Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução mais simples do que reinstalar todo o linux é tentar remover todos os pacotes que você instalou usando:

```
  sudo apt-get purge <nome_do_pacote>
```

Logo depois use:

```
  apt-get autoremove
```

Para eliminar qualquer pacote que tenha sobrado e faça a instalação do Lamp Server usando o seguinte comando:

```
  apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Isto irá marcar todos os pacotes necessários e fara a instalação facilmente para você.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Já estou com tudo resolvido, mas a resposta foi boa